# Strange performing of map data type

Tags: go, goland, oracle-golden-gate

I am trying to add a bunch of values in a map data type and after that trying to print it out. But it is performing strangely. When I am directly calling the map with the key it is giving me the correct output but not giving me any output when I am storing the key in a variable and then calling it. I am not been able to figure it out what is happening and why am I getting this kind of output. Can Somebody help me with the same.

```
package main

import (
"bufio"
"fmt"
"os"
)
func main(){
type Authentication struct {
    password string
}
var authentication = map[string]Authentication{}

var user1 Authentication
user1.password = "abc"
authentication["def"] = user1

reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
usid := readString(reader)

fmt.Println(authentication)
fmt.Println(authentication[usid])
fmt.Println(authentication["def"])
}
// Reading input functions
func readString(reader *bufio.Reader) string {
s, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
    if s[i] == '\n' {
        return s[:i]
    }
}
return s
}
```

**Input**:

```
def
```

**Output**:

```
map[def:{abc}]

{abc}
```

Comment: Use bufio.Scanner to read lines with line terminators trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do the same thing twice in readString. But all you have to do is to cut it by one byte.

```golang
func readString(reader *bufio.Reader) string {
    s, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    return s[:len(s)-1]
}
```

Comment: please go through the question once more.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/lYuur-e6oMR

Comment: I think you are correct that i need to trim off last character from the inputed string but I have tried the way you are doing, it doesn't works. you can check it

Comment: Send me something reproducible. The playground above runs without the issue.

Comment: @help_seeker See https://play.golang.org/p/mitNvUSrQNm for an example of input that does not work.

Comment: Ew, windows' \r.

Answer (score 1):

The program in the question does not work when `\r\n` is used as the line terminator in stdin.  The program removes the trailing `\n` from the line, but not the `\r`.

Fix by using [bufio.Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) instead of bufio.Reader to read lines from the input.  The bufio.Scanner type removes line terminators.

```
func main() {
    type Authentication struct {
        password string
    }
    var authentication = map[string]Authentication{}

    var user1 Authentication
    user1.password = "abc"
    authentication["def"] = user1

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    if !scanner.Scan() {
        log.Fatal(scanner.Err())
    }
    usid := scanner.Text()

    fmt.Println(authentication)
    fmt.Println(authentication[usid])
    fmt.Println(authentication["def"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can always be a better way of reading string, but I see your code works too. I ran it in my local and it gives the expected output:
[image]

From your description, I presume you are using go playground or any such platform. If that is so, the thing is, go playground doesn't take standard input, and your code has reader on `os.Stdin`. When I copy your code to playground and add the following line to check,

```golang
fmt.Printf("Length of usid: %d\nusid: %q\n", len(usid), usid)
```

I see the following output:

```
Length of usid: 0
usid: ""
```

**Conclusion: There is no issue with variables, map or code, but just the stdin.**

Comment: See [this program on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OY9L8_Ns2uf) where stdin has the `\r\n` line terminators typical on Windows.  The program does not handle the input correctly.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I'm not sure you're coming from problem to solution, or backwards. If you know already know that Windows uses CRLF (\r\n), which is 2 characters, filter both in your if statement `if s[i] == '\n' || s[i] == '\r' {return s[:i]}` 
I've tried same as earlier with this in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/S_Ebpb0pLS-).

Comment: Let me make my point more explicit.  Your conclusion that there are no issues with the OP's code is incorrect.  OP's code does not handle `\r\n` line terminators.